# C# distinguishing incoming objects using attribute

Tags: c#

I need a way of distinguishing class objects which a user is passing into my custom control. The reason for this, is so I can handle certain logic on the back end, completely extracted and uncontrollable by the user. The user would pass in object collections like this...

```
<Grid>
    <nexus:NexusEditor 
        SourceTeams="{Binding Teams}"
        SourcePlayers="{Binding Players}"
        SourceLocations="{Binding Locations}"/>
</Grid>
```

If i were to forloop through all these objects in my custom control, I need a way of marking the incoming objects so i know which **Source** there were passed through.

Comment: its super messy and risky to do that at runtime. you could make them use a standard interface at compile time or automapper might be your friend.

Comment: This can't be done at runtime, and if it was possible, shouldn't be done at runtime

Comment: this really sounds like a case where you want composition, not inheritance. trying to dynamically inherit stuff at runtime is really difficult and you're just gonna end up hurting yourself. try to look into an interface based solution.

Comment: alright, maybe ill look into doing an interface.

Comment: Could you please provide "User" code, e.g. how your user want to use this hierarchy?

Comment: "The reason I need them to inherit from the base class is so i can set the property type in code, without requiring the user to add this property to all their classes." For what reason?  Since it's not in the compiled definition there's nothing you can do with it at compile-time.

Comment: You are not telling us everything. I 100% sure there is a better design pattern to what you want to do. Please give as some background of your scenario. Where does this object come from?

Comment: " I don't want to user to have the ability to control this attribute being set" So give it a public getter but a private setter.  It really sounds like you're stuck on the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an Aspect Oriented approach where you generate proxy classes at runtime with the added behavior. But there's probably an easier way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: "so i can set the property type in code" what do you mean by this? in what code? in the base class? how could you possibly know what the type value should be at compile time if you don't even know what or how many classes will implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be easily done at runtime and is arguably the wrong design in C#. There are other ways to solve this. You can, for example,  create a wrapper around the `Connection` class and inject an instance of `Connection` into it. ConnectionWrapper can then inherit `AbstractBase`

```
public class ConnectionWrapper: AbstractBase
{
   public ConnectionWrapper(Connection connnection)
   {

   }

   private override int _type {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to give something concrete without knowing more about your requirements, but I think something like this might do what you want:

```
public interface ITyped
{
    int Type { get; }
}

public class Connection : ITyped
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // NOTE: public setters are Bad Code(tm) for anything but the dumbest DTO objects

    public int Type { get { return 1; } } // specify type for connections here
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var typed in connections.Concat<ITyped>(groups))
{
    DoStuffWith(typed);
}
```